# HDMI to SPDIF (audio extraction from HDMI)

Tags: hdmi

Is it possible to extract SPDIF signal from HDMI port without any chip? I want to extract digital audio signal from HDMI port and then route it to DAC.

([comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/564810/hdmi-to-spdif-audio-extraction-from-hdmi#comment1475679_564810) added to question) I'm searching for a chip.

Comment: There's plenty of devices that do this sold as "HDMI audio extractor" for about $10

Comment: i'm searching for a chip :)

Comment: Buy one and take it apart? Otherwise you've just got to browse digikey - we don't like recommending specific parts here because that information goes out of date very quickly.

Comment: FWIW, my HDMI to S/PDIF audio extractor uses a Lattice Sil933. (I didn’t buy the chip, but opened a cheap box from Amazon.)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is most definitely not possible without a chip that does it.

Comment: can you recommend any simple and available chips?

Comment: No, because suggesting what to buy is off-topic. Besides you asked if it is possible without a chip. And you can't buy chips that can receive encrypted content so most likely you actually don't want to buy a chip either.